# How to control downsampling of glide in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I am using Glide to set background image in activity because don't found anly solution to set background efficiently of activity which has resolution 1500 * 1000.
But the issue is glide downsampling too much and gradients inside image looking like tiles.

Comment: post your code you are using for Glide image load